# Problems to display pdf in PagePanel

Tags: java, pdf, runtime-error, bufferunderflowexception

I'm having trouble viewing a page in PagePanel, when trying to display the pdf, error occurs "java.nio.BufferUnderflowException."

Error:

> java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
>       at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.decode.RunLengthDecode.decode(RunLengthDecode.java:64)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.decode.RunLengthDecode.decode(RunLengthDecode.java:96)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.decode.PDFDecoder.decodeStream(PDFDecoder.java:134)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.PDFObject.decodeStream(PDFObject.java:347)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.PDFObject.getStream(PDFObject.java:261)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.PDFObject.getStream(PDFObject.java:298)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage.getImage(PDFImage.java:306)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer.drawImage(PDFRenderer.java:274)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.PDFImageCmd.execute(PDFPage.java:665)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer.iterate(PDFRenderer.java:577)
>       at com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.run(BaseWatchable.java:101)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Code:

```
public class Test {

public static void setup() throws IOException {

    //set up the frame and panel
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("PDF Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    PagePanel panel = new PagePanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //load a pdf from a byte buffer
    File file = new File("C:\\testeImpressora\\Print\\pdf\\tutorial.pdf");
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,  0, channel.size());
    PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);

    // show the first page
    PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(0);


    panel.showPage(page);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test.setup();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

}}
```

Comment: what line shoots the exception?

Comment: See this link  http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/PDF/Using+the+PDF+Viewer+Component it may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Path I used the same code on my Pc Path and worked good using PDFRenderer-full-0.9.1 Jar, I think you should check your Jar file.

Comment: There is no separate jar as -full. its a zip which contains the same jar file as PDFRenderer-0.9.1 and it still gives error